# I keep getting the error: There is already an object named fk_driver_id and i'm not sure how to fix this error. Help :(

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, syntax-error

```
If exists (select * from Information_schema.TABLES where 
TABLE_NAME='fd_driver_vehicles') 
Drop table fd_Driver_vehicles 
GO

If exists (select * from Information_schema.TABLES where 
TABLE_NAME='fd_vehicles') 
Drop table fd_vehicles
GO

If exists (select * from Information_schema.TABLES where 
TABLE_NAME='fd_driver_territories') 
Drop table fd_driver_territories
GO

If exists (select * from Information_schema.TABLES where 
TABLE_NAME='fd_sizes') 
Drop table fd_sizes
GO

If exists (select * from Information_schema.TABLES where 
TABLE_NAME='fd_drivers') 
Drop table fd_drivers
GO

create table fd_drivers
(
    driver_id int not null,
    driver_lastname varchar(50) not null,
    driver_firstname varchar(50) not null,
    driver_charge money not null,
    constraint pk_drivers primary key(driver_id),
    constraint ck_driver_charge check (driver_charge >0)
)

create table fd_sizes
(
    size_id char(1) not null,
    size_charge money not null,
    constraint pk_sizes primary key(size_id),
    constraint ck_size_charge check (size_charge >0)
)

create table fd_driver_territories
(
    driver_id int not null,
    driver_territory varchar(20) not null,
    constraint pk_driver_territories 
        primary key(driver_id, driver_territory),
    constraint fk_driver_id foreign key (driver_id)
        references fd_drivers (driver_id)

)

create table fd_vehicles
(
    vehicle_lp varchar(12) not null,
    vehicle_make varchar(50) not null,
    vehicle_model varchar(50) not null,
    vehicle_size char(1) not null,
    constraint pk_vehicles
        primary key(vehicle_lp),
    constraint fk_vehicle_size foreign key (vehicle_size)
        references fd_sizes (size_id)
)

create table fd_driver_vehicles 
(
    driver_id int not null,
    vehicle_lp varchar(12) not null,
    expiration_date datetime not null,
    constraint pk_driver_vehicles
        primary key (driver_id, vehicle_lp),
    constraint fk_driver_id2 foreign key (driver_id)
        references fd_drivers (driver_id),
    constraint fk_vehicle_lp foreign key (vehicle_lp)
        references fd_vehicles (vehicle_lp)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding foreign key **fk_driver_id**  which already exists so it is throwing error, delete first entry and then add new one.

Or Change name of it to Some other name.

Comment: you have a foreign key in the table or database with same name already, so its saying it alreadt exists